# Manga where the MC has a skill to copy skills of those he kills, not "berserk of gluttony", it starts in a alley

Tags: story-identification, manga

Basically MC starts out in an alleyway where he fights some bandits and eventually kills them and takes their skills, a girls skills was also taken in that alleyway, he eventually fights a female swordswomen too and takes her skills as well and she falls for him as she was bested by him. This manga has eluded me for a long time now.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately when (what year) did you read this?  Do you remember where you found it?  How about the names of any of the characters?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Does he need to do anything to steal their skills, or is it automatic when he kills them? In particular, how does he steal the skills from the swordswoman? It doesn't sound like she dies.

Answer (score 1):

*SSS-Class suicide hunter* maybe? It has [a TVTropes page](https://tvtropes.org/Literature/SSSClassSuicideHunter), so you can see if it matches.

The man character can pick on skill card from a person he is killed by. So he goes around gathering these abilities by getting himself killed over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Is it *Rise of the Outlaw Tamer and His Wild S-Rank Cat Girl*? [Amazon Sample available](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BT5VYFRB)

I do not think it is these:

*Ore no Kantei Skill ga Cheat Sugite* [Some info here](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/ore-no-kantei-skill-ga-cheat-sugite)

*Ubau Mono Ubawareru Mono* [Amazon link here, but no samples.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/4047302287)

I think it may be another manga, where a tamer tames a human.

Comment: You could improve this answer by editing it to explain how _Rise of the Outlaw Tamer and His Wild S-Rank Cat Girl_ matches the OP's description.

Answer (score 0):

[F-Class Destiny Hunter](https://myanimelist.net/manga/158399/F-Rank_Fortune_Hunter)
MC has to kill to be able to steal/copy abilities.

Comment: Any extra details you could [edit] in? Does it start in an alley with a fight against bandits? A plot synopsis would help, too

Comment: Welcome to [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](/tour)! Please [edit] your answer to add more details on how this work answers the question. You can find [tips on how to write a good story identification answer and what details to add in our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/7957).